# How to store the Query result into an Integer In Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, userform

I have written a query inside the combobox1_change event

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()



   On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
   Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim result As Integer

   cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
         "Data Source=C:\Users\inkapb\Desktop\EPC Database\EPC TOOL.mdb"
   rst.Open "SELECT [Project_Id] FROM [Project Details] WHERE [Project Name] = '" & Me.ComboBox2.Value & "' ;", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic





UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit


End Sub
```

The result of the above query is integer, could any one please tell me how to store the query result into result(int) variable.

Comment: Avoid many database connection calls just to retrieve one row one column value. Consider opening connection once, retrieve query result of multiple needed projects, save in another tab/range, and do local lookup with combo box change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read like so:

```
rst.Open ....

dim value as long

if not rst.eof then 
     value = rst.collect(0)
else
    ''no rows
end if
```